# Excel Conditional Formatting: Add border to row if cell not blank? But ignore formula?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet with index match formulas running down column B like so:

```
Column B        Column C        Column D        Column E
=IndexMatch
=IndexMatch
=IndexMatch
=IndexMatch
```

If my formula returns a result then it might look like this:

```
 Column B        Column C        Column D        Column E
 Value 1
 Value 2
```

What i want to do is add conditional formatting to the non blank rows and add a bottom border to range B to E for that row, so the rows with a returned value,

So the rows with value 1 and value 2 in would have a border but the other rows won't.

I'm trying to use this:

```
=COUNTA($B14)>0
```

but this adds a border to all my rows with formulas in not just the one returning a result.

Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

Comment: how about `=$B14 <> ""`?

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks this worked. Seems so simple

Answer (score 2):

1. Select cells B2:E2
2. On the Home Ribbon, Click Conditional Formatting -> New Rule -> Use a formula to determine which cells to format
3. In **format values where this formula is true** enter

   =NOT(ISBLANK(B2))
4. Click Format button and do formating
5. Ok, apply

[image]

Comment: ISBLANK will not work as the OP says the cells have formulas and ISBLANK will return False if there are formulas that are returning an empty string `""`

Comment: Do not use **=NOT(ISBLANK(B2))**. Instead, use **=not(exact(b2, ""))**

Comment: or more simply `=b2<>""`